Properness of quotient map
I am new to algebraic spaces and stacks. My question is the following:

Let $X$ be a scheme and $G$ be a group scheme action on $X$. Let $[X/G]$ be the quotient stack. Then when the natural map $\pi: X \to [X/G]$ is proper?

For finite group action $X \to [X/G]$ is a finite morphism so it is proper. What will happen for an infinite group like $\mathbb{G}_m$ or others?

In general if $X/G$ is the algebraic space then when is the map proper?


Assuming X nonempty, this map is proper iff G is proper (I am assuming everything is over some base field k). Indeed, the map is a G-torsor, so its fibre above a geom pt of [X/G] is G.

@PiotrAchinger Thank you for your comment. Can you tell any reference where i get a proof of this torsor statement?

As @PiotrAchinger writes in the comments, if $X$ is nomepty, $X \to [X/G]$ is proper iff $G$ is proper.
Here is a proof. Properness is fpqc local on the source (and preserved under arbitrary base change) so $X \to [X/G]$ is proper iff its base change along $T \to [X/G]$ is proper for any map from a scheme $T$. By definition the data of a map $T \to [X/G]$ is a $G$-torsor $P \to X$ equipped with a $G$-equivariant map $P \to X$. The base change of $X \to [X/G]$ along $T \to [X/G]$ is exactly the map $P \to T$.
Therefore, we need to show that $G$ is proper iff every $G$-torsor $P \to T$ is proper for any scheme $T$. This follows from descent since $P \to T$ is fppf locally isomorphic to $G \times T \to T$ which is proper iff $G$ is.
